# How to delete all words with "-" before in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm totally new to regex and can't figure out how to realize it via Javascript.

For example, I have the string `var string = "-just an example -string for stackoverflow"`. The expected result is `string = "an example for stackoverflow"`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: With 1K+ rep you should know how to create a [mcve] with effort. For example search google for _javascript regex find and replace words starting with_ -  took me < 10 seconds

Comment: `str = str.replace(/(-\S+)/g,"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with simple `forEach`.

```js
var string = "-just an example -string for stackoverflow";
var strArray = string.split(' ');
strArray.forEach(function(value, i){
  if(value.startsWith('-')){
    strArray.splice( i, 1 )
  }
});
console.log(strArray.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-\w+\s+
```

and replace by empty

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/14)

```js
const regex = /-\w+\s+/gm;
const str = `-just an example -string for stackoverflow`;
const subst = ``;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```